# Finding the values of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when $s = 2x^2+7x$ and $s = 0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> A ball moves in the air according to equations $s = 2x^2+7x$ and $y = 3s^3-5s$. Find all values of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when $s = 0$.

I misinterpreted the question.  I plugged the $s$ equation into the values of $s$ in the $y$ equation. Then took $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and solved for critical points.  That was incorrect.  And now I don't quite understand what the question was really asking.

Comment: Where is your attempt at the solution?

Comment: OK, found them.  Now what?  (People here usually want to see what you've tried before offering homework assistance.)

Comment: I misinterpreted the question. I plugged t equation into the values of t in the y equation. Then took dy/dx and solved for critical points. that was incorrect.

Comment: and now I don't quite understand what the question was really asking..

Comment: @TheLegend: Those are good things to put into the body of the question: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult ["How to ask a good question?"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Plugging the $t$ equation into the $y$ equation is not a bad thing. But you don't want the critical points of $\frac{dy}{dx}$, you want the value of that for all values of $x$ such that $t = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer To do this do I need to find the derivative I know this, but I don't know what points to take next

Comment: For what values of $x$ is $t = 0$? (Please don't look at the answer yet.)

Comment: @DanielFischer meaning any solution where t would equal 0?

Comment: Yes, that's right, any solution for $x$ when $s=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that when $t=0$, you will have $x=0$ or $x= -\frac 7 2$ (just solve a $2$nd degree equation). Call any of them $x_0$. By the chain rule,

$$\frac {\Bbb d y} {\Bbb d x} (x_0)= \frac {\Bbb d y} {\Bbb d t} (0) \frac {\Bbb d t} {\Bbb d x} (x_0) = (9t^2 - 5) \big| _{t=0} (4x + 7) \big| _{x=x_0} = -5 (4x_0 + 7) .$$

This will give you two results: in $x_0=0$ you will get $-35$ and in $x_0= -\frac 7 2$ you will get $35$.

Answer (score 1):

While the approach in the other answer is good, you can get the derivative by using the chain rule.  The chain rule states that 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{ds}\cdot\frac{ds}{dx}.
$$

In this case, since $y=3s^3-5s$, $\frac{dy}{ds}=9s^2-5$.

Similarly, since $s=2x^2+7x$, $\frac{ds}{dx}=4x+7$.

Therefore, 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=(9s^2-5)(4x+7).
$$
You could write this in terms of $x$ by substituting the formula for $s$, but since $s$ should be zero, you can simply substitute $0$ for $s$.

Comment: The "other answer" can't be good since its author obtains $0$ as his result.

Comment: @AlexM. I meant that the other approach is good.  Edited to reflect that change.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $y=3s^3-5s$. Setting $s=2x^2+7x$, we get

$$
\begin{align}
y&=3(2x^2+7x)^3-5(2x^2+7x)\\
y&=24x^6+252x^5+882x^4+1029x^3-10x^2-35x\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=144x^5+1260x^4+3528x^3+3087x^2-20x-35\tag 1
\end{align}
$$

Now, setting $s=0$ in $s=2x^2+7x$, we get

$$
x(2x+7)=0\\
x\in\lbrace0,-\frac{7}{2}\rbrace
$$

At $x=0$

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{x=0}&=(144x^5+1260x^4+3528x^3+3087x^2-20x-35)_{x=0}\\
\ =-35
\end{align}
$$

At $x=\frac{-7}{2}$

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{x=-7/2}&=144\left(\frac{-7}{2}\right)^5+1260\left(\frac{-7}{2}\right)^4+3528\left(\frac{-7}{2}\right)^3+3087\left(\frac{-7}{2}\right)^2-20\left(\frac{-7}{2}\right)-35\\
&=70-35\\
&=35
\end{align}
$$